# PlayFramework2 Passing List to main.scala

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1, scala-template

Am using Play2.1 for one of my projects.

Am trying to create a dynamic menu in the `main.scala.html` so that it is extendible in all sub-pages.

but how should I pass a `List` to `main.scala.html`  ..

I tried on a subpage like this

```
@(menu: List[Rights])
...
@for((l, index) <- menu.zipWithIndex){
    <span class="data-@index">@l.rightName</span>
}
```

.. That was working I can see the listed rights but all I wanted is to display these rights in `main.scala.html` ..Kindly suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `@(title: String)(content: Html)` at the beginning of the main.

Have you tried something like `@(title: String, menu:List[Rights])(content: Html)`?

You should be able to even add a default parameter, like `@(title: String, menu:List[Rights] = Nil)(content: Html)`